# Plunker Text Expansion

Tags: plunker

I was watching a video where the presenter had plnkr.co open on an html editor, and typed:

```
#container
```

and then did something, and it expanded to:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

What is this called, and how does one do it in plunker?

Comment: It's called Emmet: http://plnkr.co/edit/BtECpP?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. It's not working for me, but that gives me help for troubleshooting.